# Work with the (implicit) solution to a non-linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

I solved the following non-linear differential equation with mathematica  ($x\geq 0$ and $y(0)=p$)

$$\frac{r \left(a-b e^{2 y(x)}+c e^{y(x)}+d e^{\frac{(l+r) y(x)}{l}}\right)}{f-g e^{y(x)}+h e^{\frac{(l+r) y(x)}{l}}}+y'(x)=0$$

the implicit solution for y(x) is

$$\int_1^{y(x)} \frac{g e^{s}-h e^{\frac{(l+r) s}{l}}-f}{-b e^{2 K[1]}+c e^{s}+d e^{\frac{(l+r) s}{l}}+a} \, ds=\int_1^p \frac{g e^{v}-h e^{\frac{(l+r) v}{l}}-f}{-b e^{2 v}+c e^{v}+d e^{\frac{(l+r) v}{l}}+a} \, dv+r x$$

I tried to find some way to obtain an analytical solution to y(x) from this without success. Any clues?

Comment: Change the rule of $x$ and $y$ in your equation.

Comment: What do you mean @MyGlasses?

Comment: I think what @MyGlasses wanted to say is that if we can guarantee that on a some interval the function $x\to y(x)$ is $C^1$-invertible, then we can to write the differential equation on the function $y\to x(y)$.